# How to elegantly solve this rounding issue?

Tags: c++, rounding

I have this function that has 20 attempts to "guess" a number in the range 1-100:

```
int guess(int number) {
    int start = 1;
    int end = 100;
    int count = 20;
    int answer = 0;

    while (count--) {
        int half = start + round((double)(end - start) / 2);
        if (number < half) end = half;
        else if (number > half) start = half;
        else {
            answer = half;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (answer > 0) return 20 - count;
    else return 0;    
}
```

The problem is that as it is right now rounding the result of the range halving, it cannot guess the number 1, and if I don't round, it cannot guess the other extreme of the range - 100.

The source of the issue is obvious as is the crude hack solution, but I don't seem to find an elegant way of solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know, that is easily corrected:

**Do not keep the mid-point in the range of possibilities after checking it**, it is not possible!

Why do you have those troubles? Because you are working with closed ranges instead of half-open ranges, as would be sensible.

As an aside, use integer arithmetic, like this:

```
    int half = (start + end) / 2;
```

(Integer-division rounds towards 0)

Comment: @user3735658: Try it. Remember not to leave the mid-point in those ranges though. Anyway, reworded to make the actual error and its root-cause obvious.

Comment: This is more I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of ceiling and floor depending of the side where the value reside.

So if your looking a value in the top side, then use floor (5.9 -> 5) and if you're looking for a value below the half, then use ceiling ( 90.2 = 91).

This should make your process include 1 and 100

Comment: I tried keeping `half` a double until the checking and then assign end and start to floor or ceil, which works but it does increase the number of tries for all values, so it doesn't really qualify as very elegant IMO.

Comment: In fact it adds quite a lot of overhead. For example 51 is guessed in 1 try, 26 in 2 and so on, but with this approach it takes 8 tries for those same numbers. The total number of tries for all numbers in range increases from 573 to 700.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it may take one more loop in some cases. Initializing end to 101 eliminates the issue with integer division rounding down (start could also be set to 0, but it's not needed). The code could also just check for 1 or 100 before doing the loop, but I'm not sure if that would count as two more loops.

```
int j;
int start;
int end;
int half;
    for(j = 1; j < 101; j++){
        start = 1;
        end = 101;
        while(1){
            half = (start + end)/2;
            if(half == j)
                break;
            if(half < j)
                start = half;
            else
                end = half;
        }
        printf("%3d\n", half);
    }
```